# Angular/Typescript call a class method in an event

Tags: angular, typescript

I am totals new to TS and Angular and I am trying to build a simple drawing component on a canvas. I have so far worked my way to a point where I totally don't know what I am doing. The different "this" in Ts was a BIG issue for me, but I think I get it now. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'track-creator',
    templateUrl: 'track-creator.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['track-creator.component.css']
})

export class TrackCreatorComponent implements OnInit {
    public canvas;
    public context;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('trackCreatorCanvas');
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            this.draw(e);
        }, false);
    }

    draw(e): void{
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(e.clientX,e.clientY,5,0,2*Math.PI);
        this.context.stroke();
    }
}
```

The error here is:

> ERROR TypeError: this.draw is not a function

I have done some reading on TS, but I still cant understand what to do in this situation. I'm not retarded (not too much at least), but I don't know much about TS. Please have this in mind when you try to explain me my error.

Comment: this refers to the class (TrackCreatorComponent), and is used to access the properties and methods of the class. this is a javascript thing not specifically a TypeScript thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    this.draw(e);
}, false);
```

try writing this:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    this.draw(e);
}, false);
```

When you create a new function without a lambda expression, `this` refers to the context of that function. The lambda expression preserves the context of `this`

Try going `console.log(this)` in the first example and do it again in the second example to get a clearer view of what this means.

Comment: Just curious, where does the term 'lambda expression' come from?

Comment: Well I don't know, it seems like it comes from [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) somehow.

Comment: Yeah but I don't see why an arrow function is suddenly a lambda while a regular old fashioned function isn't... :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also I tried the little experiment, in the first case `this` refers to the canvas and in the second it refers tho an instance of the component. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling a drawing function inside an `.addEventListener` method?
That is supposed to be listening to the `mousedown` not drawing on the canvas. You are supposed to give it an x and y cordinate there based on `e`. Not draw there.

Here some example:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   public canvas;
   public context;
   public mous ={x:undefined,y:undefined}

ngOnInit(){
   this.canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
   this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
   this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
   this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
   this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        this.mous.x=e.x; //getting the cordinates x
        this.mous.y=e.y; //getting the cordinates y

    }, false);
     this.draw(this.mous.x,this.mous.y)

}

//you can improve this but you can change it like this 
draw(x,y){
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(x, y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.context.fillStyle ="black";
    this.context.fill();
}

}
```

The `draw()` method is not doing anything nor listen.